# Filter ConcurrentHashMap by value

Tags: java, java-8, filtering, java-stream, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to filter a `ConcurrentHashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>` by the size of the `LinkedList<String>`.

In other words, I want to filter out elements in `ConcurrentHashMap` where the size of `LinkedList<String>` is greater than 4. How would I get it done by Java 8?

Comment: what do you mean by 'filter'? what is your filter criteria? please add more info

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have a `ConcurrentMap`, you can simply create a stream of its entries, by calling [`entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) and then [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) and keep the entries where the value has a length greater than 4 by applying a [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-). Finally, you can collect that again into a `ConcurrentMap` with the built-in [`Collectors.toConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-).

```
ConcurrentMap<String, LinkedList<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

ConcurrentMap<String, LinkedList<String>> result = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 4)
       .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Alternatively, you could do it in-place by modifying the map with

```
map.values().removeIf(l -> l.size() <= 4);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that works. One minor correction - `Map<String, LinkedList<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();` otherwise compiler says `getKey` and `getValue` cannot be resolved